# Chrome.commands shortcuts

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-app, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have been trying to set my moving tab shortcut,
within chrome
"cmd + shift + ] | [ "
you can navigate within tabs, and I made a extension to be able to move tabs to. Right now my shortcut for moving tabs is "cmd + control + right arrow | left arrow"

but I am looking to optimize my workflow by changing it to:
"cmd + control + ] | [ " but chrome.commands doesn't allow keys like " [ ] " to be added in the extension shortcut. Is there anyway to bypass this? How does chrome have the shortcut for navigating with "[]" keys in the first place then?